# Is there an equality operator for the test funcion in CLIPS? Also, how do nested or's work?

Tags: logical-operators, equality, clips

Good morning everyone!

As part of my thesis for my masters, I am trying to write some code in CLIPS for predicting the taste 37 subjects have perceived and compare it to the actual-known flavors that we had given them on the experiment. We have used an array of 122 EMG leads and recorded brain activity while they were experiencing each taste.

I used WEKA to create a hierarchical tree of the leads so that I'll keep only the most important ones which are related to brain areas for perceiving taste, leading down to 20.

Based on the tree from WEKA I'm trying to create this smart system for making predictions about what taste might a new subject experience, only with us "looking" in their EMG activity.

So...

I use the following rule to find among my facts, those which fulfill the following:

```
(test (or    (or(eq ?L7 -5);Meaning that: test if L7 is either -5, -4, -4, -2, 2
                (eq ?L7 -4)
                (eq ?L7 -3)
                (eq ?L7 -2)
                (eq ?L7 2))
         ;OR
             (  (eq ?L7 -1);or test weather 
                (or(eq ?L120 -5)     ;L7 is -1 AND L120 is -5 or
                   (eq ?L120 -4)     ;L7 is -1 AND L120 is -4 or
                   (eq ?L120 -3)     ;L7 is -1 AND L120 is -3 or
                   (eq ?L120 -1)     ;L7 is -1 AND L120 is -1 or
                   (eq ?L120 1)      ;L7 is -1 AND L120 is 1 or
                   (eq ?L120 2)      ;L7 is -1 AND L120 is 2 or
                   (eq ?L120 3)      ;L7 is -1 AND L120 is 3 or
                   (eq ?L120 4)      ;L7 is -1 AND L120 is 4 or
                   (eq ?L120 5))     ;L7 is -1 AND L120 is 5 
             )
           ;OR
            (   (eq ?L7 0)       ;OR weather 
                (eq ?L60 -4)     ;L7 is 0 and L60 is -4
            )
```

...etc...

What I get from this when I run it is a message saying:

```
[EXPRNPSR1] A function name must be a symbol

ERROR:
(defrule MAIN::rule1
    (declare (salience 60))
    (?f <- (facts (id ?id) (L7 ?L7) (L20 ?L20) (L23 ?L23) (L26 ?L26) ;other parameters follow ...
    (test (or (or (eq ?L7 -5) (eq ?L7 -4) (eq ?L7 -3) (eq ?L7 -2) (eq ?L7 2)) ((
```

And there it stops, obviously implying that my syntax for nested or's in the test function are not correctly used.

Also I wonder about the "test weather equal function". I have used in the past

```
(test (<= ?L7 2))
```

and I know it works, but it didn't work for "==" (aka equal). The next best thing I found was "eq" function.

Still no luck.

I am sorry for my silly questions, but I'm new in CLIPS (and generally I'm a doctor not a programmer (yet!)), so any help would be appreciated.

So what am I doing wrong? How should the syntax be for what I'm stating in the ;comments of my code?

Thank you in advance!

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows the point at which the error occurred:

```
         CLIPS (6.30 3/17/15)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate facts
  (slot id)
  (slot L7)
  (slot L20)
  (slot L23)
  (slot L26))
CLIPS> 
(defrule MAIN::rule1
    (declare (salience 60))
    ?f <- (facts (id ?id) (L7 ?L7) (L20 ?L20) (L23 ?L23) (L26 ?L26))
    (test (or (or (eq ?L7 -5) 
                  (eq ?L7 -4) 
                  (eq ?L7 -3) 
                  (eq ?L7 -2) 
                  (eq ?L7 2)) 
               (()))) 
    =>)     

[EXPRNPSR1] A function name must be a symbol

ERROR:
(defrule MAIN::rule1
   (declare (salience 60))
   ?f <- (facts (id ?id) (L7 ?L7) (L20 ?L20) (L23 ?L23) (L26 ?L26))
   (test (or (or (eq ?L7 -5) (eq ?L7 -4) (eq ?L7 -3) (eq ?L7 -2) (eq ?L7 2)) ((
CLIPS>
```

In this case, the error occurs at the point where two left parentheses "((" are encountered. Unlike languages which allow infix operators and use parentheses to specify precedence, you can't use additional parentheses in CLIPS. So **(+ 3 4)** is valid syntax, but **((+ 3 4))** is not. Since the final **(** is the last token parsed, the error message indicates that it was expecting that token to be a function name.

For numeric equality comparisons, use the **=** function.

Comment: thank you so much for this answer. 

But then, how do I code this bit where I have used 2 left parentheses in a row?

```...
         ;OR
   ;or test weather 
   ;L7 is -1 AND L120 is -5 or
   ;L7 is -1 AND L120 is -4 or
   ;L7 is -1 AND L120 is -3 or
   ;L7 is -1 AND L120 is -1 or
   ;L7 is -1 AND L120 is 1 or
   ;L7 is -1 AND L120 is 2 or
   ;L7 is -1 AND L120 is 3 or
   ;L7 is -1 AND L120 is 4 or
   ;L7 is -1 AND L120 is 5 
             )
           ;OR
            ( ```



? I can not find any clear documentation on how to code that segment.

Comment: Use the and function: (and (eq ?L7 -1) (or (eq ?L120 -5) (eq ?L120 -4) ...))